# How to return a json response in twisted?

Tags: python, json, twisted

When I am using django: I always do

```
return HttpResponse(json.dumps(result), mimetype='application/json')
```

How can I do this in twisted? Official document do not say this.

document [here](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/web/howto/using-twistedweb.html)

Only `Serving WSGI Applications` can set `mimetype`.But I want to process  GET and POST
There is no more example, and I searched with nothing found.

```
from twisted.web import resource
class MyGreatResource(resource.Resource):
    def render_GET(self, request):
        return "xxxx"
```

It return raw string

Comment: there re many modules out sere to create json objects. just use one of them and send the result on the wire.

Comment: @vikingosegundo convert object to json is simple, but twisted can not set `minetype` as I see.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Encoded JSON *is* a (byte) string.

If your question is "How do I set the Content-Type of the response to `application/json`?" then the answer is:

```
request.responseHeaders.addRawHeader(b"content-type", b"application/json")
```

Comment: Yes, thanks. Maybe my question title is not so clearly,because I think everyone can understand my question means...